# Remote Access to Kubuntu from Windows

Tags: kubuntu, remote-desktop

I've got it to work so I can get to it with TightVNC but the Kubuntu machine keeps changing the password.  I want to have a fixed password for remote access to the machine which is there when it starts up.  At the moment I have to enter a password for the KDE Wallet and change the password for unattended remote access every time I restart the Linux box.  Can anyone suggest how I can get it to remember the password and or not require a password for or not use KDE Wallet?

Thanks.

Comment: Just be aware that VNC is an insecure protocol. I would suggest ssh (putty and xming on windows) or freenx which is faster and more secure.

Comment: freenx appears to have stopped at Trusty.  I'm on Bionic.

Answer (score 2):

In the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#krfb) for VNC servers, there's an entry about `krfb` which
seems to be the *default vnc server* for Kubuntu.

I'll assume this is what you're using.

It says:

```
To configure krfb, go to System Settings > Sharing > Desktop Sharing > Configure....

1. To set krfb to request access each time, tick Confirm uninvited connections before accepting
```

So, to get what you need (<strike>don't ask every time for a password</strike> ask every time the same configured password and not generating a different one every time), you should **untick** the option `Confirm uninvited connections before accepting`.

**DISCLAIMER**

Please make sure to setup a secure password on the *Password* field.

**UPDATE**

To make the password persist, the correct procedure for Kubuntu >= 17.10 looks like this:

- tick the option "Enable desktop sharing"
- set a password for desktop sharing
- tick the option "Enable Unattended Access"
- set the same password for unattended access

All settings will persist over KDE sessions.

In case the passwords *cannot be changed* in `krfb`, you can change them in `kwallet`.

Comment: Except that doesn't work.  That seemed the obvious way forward but when I do it the password I set to connect uninvited doesn't stick after I restart the machine.

Comment: @JohnDoe which Kubuntu version? There was a bug regarding this ([link](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=340411)), which looks like was fixed in verison 17.10.

Comment: I'm on 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: on newer Kubuntu versions you might need to install and run `krfb` manually to get the settings window to appear

Answer (score 0):

Note that RDP would be the more natural solution over VNC. However, KRFB does not support RDP yet but only VNC. A corresponding feature request is here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455238